# pickadate.js not setting date on jquery.fancybox input

Tags: jquery, datepicker, fancybox, lightbox

I'm using date and time picker from pickadate.js -- works fine on main page, but when opening a fancybox (fancybox.net) and attaching the date picker to an input field on that layer, the calendar opens, but clicking a date does not set that date in the input field, and clicking anywhere else (to change the month) closes the calendar...really puzzled!

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/

I really appreciate the community's assistance!

AG

Comment: try initializing the pickadate script inside the `beforeShow` fancybox callback

Answer (score 0):

Probably a long shot but would it have something to do with pickadate setting the input box to read only?